# Trying to Check Archived Log Files are Correctly Copied

Tags: bash, logging, diff

I am writing a bash script to archive certain days of log files in to a different directory,

My Script for Coping is :

```
LOGROOT="/var/log/test_log4j"
LOG="$LOGROOT/"
ARCHIVE="$LOGROOT/Archive/$(date -d "7 days ago" '+%d-%m-%y')_To_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"

mkdir -p $ARCHIVE

find $LOG/* -mtime +7 -type f -print -exec cp {} $ARCHIVE \;
```

This works without issue,
After coping the file I wanted to check all the files archived successfully (copied without an issue)
For that I want to use `diff`

I am trying manually deleting one log file and executing below command in terminal:

```
find $LOG/* -mtime +7 -type f -exec bash -c 'diff $t.out -rq --no-dereference "$@" "/var/log/test_log4j/Archive/$(date -d "7 days ago" '+%d-%m-%y')_To_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"| grep "[<>]" | sed "s/>/\t/g;s/<//g"' bash {} \;
```

When tried it in terminal it's giving required output which is :

```
diff: /var/log/test_log4j/Archive/12-11-21_To_19-11-2021/log-2021-11-01.log: No such file or directory
```

I manfully deleted `log-2021-11-01.log` for sake of testing,
Now ***I could not catch it to a variable*** to write in a log file or to use in `if` statement in `Bash Shell Script`

I am checking if any issue found in copied content to the new archived file before `tar` zip.

Comment: Everything is clear until you get to your question...  Your script works, as per your question.  Then you delete a file and wonder why you cant find it anymore?  The `find` with the `diff` will not know about a file that used to be there.  Clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to know if something happens when coping let's say when script copies file something happened in between and one file was missing from the archive folder, now diff will give met the  output after comparing it with original file, I wanted to capture the output by find $LOG/* -mtime +7 -type f -exec bash -c 'diff $t.out -rq --no-dereference "$@" "/var/log/test_log4j/Archive/$(date -d "7 days ago" '+%d-%m-%y')_To_$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"| grep "[<>]" | sed "s/>/\t/g;s/<//g"' bash {} \; in a variable to use in a if

Comment: To put the output of a command into a variable, you can use `var=$(your command)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But it does not work with output-->diff: /var/log/test_log4j/Archive/12-11-21_To_19-11-2021/log-2021-11-01.log: No such file or directory